# Error Parsing Episode Number from String "One Piece Film: Z - Filme" in Go

Tags: regex, go, error-handling, string-parsing

I am developing a Go application that interacts with an anime website to download and play episodes. The application should handle both regular series with numbered episodes and movies/OVAs that do not follow the same numbering format.

The issue arises when trying to extract and convert the episode number from strings representing movies/OVAs, such as "One Piece Film: Z - Filme". Since these titles do not contain episode numbers in the expected format, the strconv.Atoi function fails to convert an empty string, resulting in the error:

```golang
Error parsing episode number 'One Piece Film: Z - Filme': strconv.Atoi: parsing "": invalid syntax
```

The relevant code snippet is as follows:

```golang
if series {
        fmt.Printf("O anime selecionado é uma série com %d episódios.\n", totalEpisodes)
        selectedEpisodeURL, episodeNumberStr := selectEpisode(episodes)
    
        // Check if the episode title contains any digits
        var selectedEpisodeNum int
        if regexp.MustCompile(`\d`).MatchString(episodeNumberStr) {
            selectedEpisodeNumStr := extractEpisodeNumber(episodeNumberStr)
            var err error
            selectedEpisodeNum, err = strconv.Atoi(selectedEpisodeNumStr)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Error parsing episode number: %v", err)
            }
        } else {
            // For movies/OVAs, set a default episode number (e.g., 1)
            selectedEpisodeNum = 1
        }
    
        videoURL, err := getVideoURLForEpisode(selectedEpisodeURL)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to extract video URL: %v", err)
        }
    
        handleDownloadAndPlay(videoURL, episodes, selectedEpisodeNum, animeURL, episodeNumberStr)
    } else {
        // Handle movies/OVAs similarly as before
        fmt.Println("O anime selecionado é um filme/OVA. Iniciando a reprodução direta...")
        videoURL, err := getVideoURLForEpisode(episodes[0].URL)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to extract video URL: %v", err)
        }
    
        handleDownloadAndPlay(videoURL, episodes, 1, animeURL, episodes[0].Number)
    }
```

The `extractEpisodeNumber` function attempts to extract a number from a string, returning "1" if no number is found:

```golang
func extractEpisodeNumber(episodeStr string) string {
    numRe := regexp.MustCompile(`\d+`)
    numStr := numRe.FindString(episodeStr)
    if numStr == "" {
        fmt.Println("No numeric episode number found, returning default value '1'")
        return "1" // Retorna "1" para filmes/OVAs
    }
    return numStr
}
```

How can I adjust my episode number extraction logic to properly handle strings for movies/OVAs, avoiding the conversion error with strconv.Atoi when the string does not contain numbers?

I am looking for a solution that allows me to reliably differentiate between series episodes and movies/OVAs and handle each case appropriately in my application.

How can I adjust my episode number extraction logic to properly handle strings for movies/OVAs, avoiding the conversion error with strconv.Atoi when the string does not contain numbers?

#### Minimal Reproducible Example

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "regexp"
    "strconv"
)

func extractEpisodeNumber(episodeStr string) string {
    numRe := regexp.MustCompile(`\d+`)
    numStr := numRe.FindString(episodeStr)
    if numStr == "" {
        return "1" // Return "1" for movies/OVAs
    }
    return numStr
}

func main() {
    episodeTitles := []string{"One Piece Episode 1", "One Piece Film: Z - Filme"}

    for _, title := range episodeTitles {
        episodeNumStr := extractEpisodeNumber(title)
        episodeNum, err := strconv.Atoi(episodeNumStr)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Error parsing episode number from '%s': %v", title, err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Parsed episode number for '%s': %d\n", title, episodeNum)
    }
}
```

##### Expected Behavior

The program should parse the episode number from the string and print it. For strings without a numeric episode number, it should default to `1`.

##### Actual Behavior

The program crashes with the following error when processing a title without a numeric episode number:

```golang
Error parsing episode number from 'One Piece Film: Z - Filme': strconv.Atoi: parsing "": invalid syntax
```

##### Steps to Reproduce

- Run the provided Go program.
- Observe the error output when processing the second title in the `episodeTitles` slice.

[full code](https://github.com/alvarorichard/GoAnime/tree/dev)

Comment: Have you tried adding a condition that checks for empty-string before passing to `strconv.Atoi`?

Comment: yes but not works

Comment: The error you're showing is not generated by the code you're showing (your error includes the movie title, your code to display the error does not). Please edit your question and include EXACTLY the code that's generating the error. Frankly, something else is happening here that you're not showing the code for because ```regexp.MustCompile(`\d`).MatchString("string without a number")``` is never going to be true.

Comment: [full code](https://github.com/alvarorichard/GoAnime/blob/dev/main.go)

Comment: @killerbyte: The best way to get help from a question is to provide a [Minimum, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that is very specific in scope, so answerers can execute it while helping. There's also a good chance that you fix the bug while creating a smaller example.

Comment: I apologize for the long post, but I prefer to err on the side of providing too much information to solve this issue rather than having people not understand. Therefore, I've added a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE). I believe that with this and the entire source code, it might help others understand.

Comment: Different point of view: You fail to get to the point. Which in turn means you have not narrowed down the problem. If you do not care, why should someone else? You do not have to explain the code to the people here. We can read Go. Also, your minimal reproducible example fails to reproduce the actual problem you describe: https://go.dev/play/p/EP5FyMgiT7g runs just fine.